# LWJGL - Why does some code exemples use GLX methods and other glX

Tags: java, lwjgl

Why do some LWJGL project's methods are in `GLx.methodName` format (x being a number) while others simply call methods as `glMethodName`?
Is it simply a different version or is it some additional API that is causing these changes?
And most importantly, what are the differences inbetween the two?

Comment: One is a class name, and refers to a whole group of methods.  The other is a single method name, and likely refers either to a static import or an instance method.

Comment: Which is the same naming convention you will see commonly used for much of the family of curly-brace languages, including Java.